# Docker container to bring up DB fails with connection refused error

Tags: postgresql, docker

Docker : Initialize database doesn't work

I have a dockerfile that sets up a db. This dockerfile is used in a docker-compose file.

When i run `$docker-compose up` I get the follwoing error:

> panic: dial tcp 172.19.0.2:5432: connect: connection refused

```
FROM postgres:9.6 
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432
ENV POSTGRES_USER=abc
ENV FLYWAY_VERSION 5.0.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget build-essential
RUN ["mkdir", "/src"]
RUN wget -q https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/$FLYWAY_VERSION/flyway-commandline-$FLYWAY_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz -P /src/
RUN tar xzf /src/flyway-commandline-$FLYWAY_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /src/ RUN chmod +x /src/flyway-$FLYWAY_VERSION/flyway
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/src/flyway-$FLYWAY_VERSION
COPY Makefile /src/ COPY migrations /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrations/ COPY flyway.test.conf /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY bin/initdb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE $POSTGRES_PORT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extending postgres docker image you need to add the entrypoint at the end of your new `Dockerfile` so you can start `postgres` service again or you can set it manually while running a new container.

By checking the original [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/Dockerfile) for `Postgres 9.6`, you can see that you are missing the following lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

Comment: I tried this and still getting the same error ...    psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
db_1  |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
db_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
db_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
db_1  |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
db_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Can you disable `initdb.sh` for a while in order to make sure that the error is not raised by this script ? Also what is the result of `docker logs` ?

Comment: `db_1  | psql --command='CREATE DATABASE test_db' 2>/dev/null || true                                                                                                  
db_1  | psql --command="CREATE USER someone WITH SUPERUSER CREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN PASSWORD 'something'" || true
    db_1  | psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    db_1  |  Is the server running locally and accepting
    db_1  |  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: I tried `ENV PGHOST=localhost` And I get : 
`db_1  | psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
db_1  |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
db_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
db_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
db_1  |  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
db_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: could you add the result of docker logs when you start the postgres container ?

Comment: i mean the result of running the entrypoint not the database initialization. can you disable initdb script then start the container again and send me the logs ?

Comment: This is the Docker log after disabling initdb script. `db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server started
db_1  | psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
db_1  |     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
db_1  |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
db_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
db_1  |     Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
db_1  |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
xyzservice_db_1 exited with code 2`

Comment: I am able to resolve the above issue by adding `EXPOSE 5432` before creating the DB. After creating the DB I need to run a flyway command to execute a set of .sql files on the same. This command is giving error now.

Comment: I would suggest that you update your docker-compose file with the username and password and db name and mount the initdb file or sql file through docker-compose so postgres container will restore the file automatically, you can review the following: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L126-L134

Comment: Thanks for your help. My issue is resolved now. I got rid of flyway and running the required sql from the initdb script directly. Followed the solution above. Thanks!